# Datacontext models with join

Tags: c#, models, datacontext

I’m trying to get details about the business when I get a deal.
I want to translate this query:

```
select d.*, b.* from deals d inner join business b
on b.id = d.businessId
where d.IsEvent = true
```

I tried it like this:

```
public List<Deal> GetEventsDeals()
{
    var deals = DataContext.Deals.Join(DataContext.Businesses,
        d => d.BusinessId,
        b => b.Id,
        (d, b) => new {Business = b, Deal = d})
        .Where(d => (d.Deal.IsEvent == true));

    return deals.OrderBy(d => d.Deal.Order).Take(50).ToList();
}
```

But I’m getting an error that I need to return `List<AnnoymousType>` and cannot convert it to `List<Deal>`.

[image]

How can I translate my query?

Comment: Please provide the actual error message

Comment: @Wndrr ok i edited the post

Comment: Apart from the error, if you have to join you have a bug in your model. You *shouldn't* need joins with EF. Like any ORM, it's EF's job to map *relations*, not the code's. The `Deal` and `Business` class should have properties that point to each other so that if you load a Deal, you'll be able to access all related businesses from its `Deal.Businesses` collection.

Comment: BTW the error *is* crystal-clear. You are trying to return a Deal, Business pair when you explicitly said that only *Deals* will be returned. If you fix your entities though, you won't have to change anything, only *delete* the join.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: That generates (a lot of) tedious queries though.

Comment: @Caramiriel ???? What? It *deletes* a lot of tedious queries. You *don't* need to write tedious queries when you have proper mappings. You have to write tedious queries like this join because the mappings are missing. In any case, if you want to write joins, why use an ORM in the first place? Just write the SQL query. Don't say "embedded SQL". Put it in a view or stored procedure. Or use Dapper

Comment: as a note: `d => (d.Deal.IsEvent == true)` can be replaced with `d => d.Deal.IsEvent == true`.

Comment: i dont understand what i need to do...
i have 2 models in deal model i have
        public int BusinessId { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("BusinessId")]
        public Business Business { get; set; }

but i got business = null when i get the data so i did a join

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos What I meant was that EF doesn't know what information you'll need prior executing the query. If you would have `DataContext.Deals.Single(x=>x.Id==123).Something.Else.Far.Away` it would create 5 queries for that already, which can be avoided with manual joining. But that's out of context for this question, I just wanted to give information to be aware of this.

Comment: It's true that EF can create a load of calls and not-so appropriate statements but I think that in this case, using an explicit join simply makes no sense. It adds a lot of code and makes it far less clear than using `.Include()`

Comment: if you use .Include(), EF will generate very heavily nested queries using sub-SELECT and APPLY statements to get the data you want. there is an bad performance issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message tells you that you are trying to convert an anonymous type to a `Deals` type, which it doesn't know how to do. You need to do it this way *for the code to work*

```
public List<Deal> GetEventsDeals()
{
    var deals = DataContext.Deals.Join(DataContext.Businesses,
        d => d.BusinessId,
        b => b.Id,
        (d, b) => new Deal(){Business = b, Deal = d})
        .Where(d => (d.Deal.IsEvent == true));

    return deals.OrderBy(d => d.Deal.Order).Take(50).ToList();
}
```

note: as pointed out by [Panagiotis Kanavos](https://stackoverflow.com/users/134204/panagiotis-kanavos), this is not the way entityframework is designed to be used. Inner joins should be replace with navigation properties.

To do this properly you should have a model like so

```
public class Deal
{
    public int BusinessId { get; set; } 
    [ForeignKey("BusinessId")] // I believe this attribute is redundant because the names follow conventions, but you should check that
    public virtual Business Business { get; set; }
    public bool IsEvent {get;set;}
    public int Order {get;set;}
}
```

so you do your call as follow

```
var deals = DataContext.Deals.Include(d => d.Business).Where(d => d.Deal.IsEvent == true);

return deals.OrderBy(d => d.Deal.Order).Take(50).ToList();
```

Comment: this is what i did but the business variable get "null"

Comment: If you use the `.include()` you get a null ? Is the value of `BusinessId ` properly set ? Can you check the database to make sure this value really points to a *valid and existing*  buisness id ?

Comment: i will check it again, tnx

Comment: Thank you for the upvote. Let me know if it still doesn't work. Keep in mind that `.Include()` is designed to do exactly what you're trying to achieve, so if it doesn't work something is wrong.

Comment: i get all rows without using where isEvent = true and all rows the business is null...

Comment: Did you check in the database ? Did you properly set the `BusinessId` when inserting the row in database ?

Comment: Well we don't have enough data to help you more. Can you please show the code/screenshots of all revelant parts of the problem such as 
the current model that you use for deal and bussness, your database, your current call to EF and such ?